# DOM parser for non xml

Tags: java, xml, dom, parsing

i want to parse the following  type of text. Example1
`<root>my name is <j> <b> mike</b>  </j> </root>`

example 2

```
<root> my name is   <mytag1 attribute="val" >mike</mytag1> and yours is <mytag2> john</mytag2> </root>
```

can i parse it using a DOM parser?I will not have the same format evry time .I can have different formats in which the tags are nested.I dont know the format in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both these examples are valid XML documents so there's no reason you can;t do this.

If your XML is very simple, especially if it combines text and tags together, you may want to run it via an [XSL transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) first, to have a format easier to parse or to convert it to other format, such as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOM parser for the examples you've given - they're valid XML. However, you wouldn't be able to use it for *non-XML* as per your subject line.

When you say you can have "different formats in which the tags are nested" what exactly do you mean? If it's always *simple* nesting, e.g.

```
<root>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      <tag3>
        Stuff
      </tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1>
</root>
```

Then that will be fine. However, an XML parser won't like markup where an "outer" tag is closed before an "inner" one:

```
<root>
  <tag1>
    <tag2>
      Stuff
    </tag1> <!-- Invalid -->
  </tag2>
</root>
```